# runapp shiny from other shiny application with actionbutton

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to call another shinny app when i push an actionbutton in a very simple shiny app. The other application is in a folder called benefits with ui.R and server.R files, but when i click the button nothing happens. Is it possible what i am trying to do??

Cheers.

### ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("RunnApp"),
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
    )

))
```

### server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
      runApp("benefits")
  })
            })
```

Comment: Is this on a server, or on your local machine?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to launch a shiny app from within another shiny app. Calling `runApp()` inside a shiny app will result in this error,

```
Warning: Error in shiny::runApp: Can't call `runApp()` from within `runApp()`. If your application code contains `runApp()`, please remove it.
```

But, with RStudio 1.2 there is a workaround. We can store `runApp()` of second app in an R script and execute this script as a separate R Studio Job. This will start the second shiny app in a new session without stopping the first one.

Code:

script.R

```
shiny::runApp(path_to_app, launch.browser = TRUE, port = 875)
```

ui.R

```
actionButton("launch_app", "Launch second Shiny App")
```

server.R

```
observeEvent(input$launch_app, {
        rstudioapi::jobRunScript(path = path_to_script)
    })
```

If this is for a package, store the script in inst/ and use system.file() to build paths.

Answer (score 1):

**TEMPORARY ANSWER:**

I have begun my search for an answer to this problem. This answer will be updated in time.

```
#server.R



library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    stopApp(runApp('C:/Users/Infinite Flash/Desktop/Dashboard'))
  })

  output$nText <- renderText({
    ntext()
  })
})



#ui.R

library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("actionButton test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("goButton", "Go!"),
    p("Click the button to update the value displayed in the main panel.")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("nText")
  )
))
```

The great thing about this code is that it initializes the app I've specified with the         `stop(runApp('C:/Users/Infinite Flash/Desktop/Dashboard'))` statement. I can verify that it does run the app as I have a global.R file in that app that has 6 pre-loaded datasets that the app needs to load in before it start. I know it ran because after this line of code runs, I have these objects (created by the global.R file in the referenced app) are in my environment.

The tricky issue is that I get this error when (I think this is the problem),  it initializes the referenced app:

**Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7908**

**Error in handlers$add(handler, key, tail) : Key / already in use**

Currently this type of error with the shiny interface, is out of my domain of knowledge. To debug this error, I'll need to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

instead of again using run-app use shinyAppDir('path to your new app').

this code is working for me.
stopApp(shinyAppDir("NewApp/"))